# How can I create Wordpress tags programmatically?

Tags: wordpress

The following snippet adds Wordpress categories programmatically. My question is how do you add tags programmatically?

```
//Define the category
$my_cat = array('cat_name' => 'My Category', 'category_description' => 'A Cool Category', 'category_nicename' => 'category-slug', 'category_parent' => '');

// Create the category
$my_cat_id = wp_insert_category($my_cat);
```

---

In this question, I'm talking about  adding the tags into database programmatically.

Say, I got 1000 tags to add to a fresh installation. And I don't want to go through the regular admin panel to add tags one by one manually. I'm looking for a programmatic solution. The snippet I posted takes care of the add of cats... thanks to the specific wp function wp_insert_category.... there is no function called wp_insert_tag though...

However, looking at the codex, I see the wp_insert_term function which may very well be the one to do the job - it seems.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`wp_insert_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) to add categories, tags and other taxonomies, because `wp_insert_category()` fires a PHP error "Undefined function".

```
<?php wp_insert_term( $term, $taxonomy, $args = array() ); ?>
```

`$term` is the term to add or update.

Change the value of `$taxonomy` into `post_tag` if it's a tag and `category` if it's a category.

In `$args` array, you can specify values of inserted term (tag, category etc.)

**Example:**

```
wp_insert_term(
  'Apple', // the term 
  'product', // the taxonomy
  array(
    'description'=> 'A yummy apple.',
    'slug' => 'apple',
    'parent'=> $parent_term['term_id']  // get numeric term id
  )
);
```

Comment: Have you gone thru the population of a wordpress database programmatically? We've got about 50 tables spanning 3-4 databases ( they all ms-sql ) and we want to bring some of that stuff ( those that could fit in the "post" concept like the media files and the articles etc ) into wordpress. So, I was planning of running a php script to do the job. Any experience in that? What other tools/functions do you think I will be needing? The idea is to first  identify the cats and tags from the existing tables and create them on the wordpress side by registering them under certain taxonomies.- Then...->

Comment: continiuing...  --> go for a second run and start populating the wp+posts table, by associating the current post with the previously created cats/tag and other taxonomies in the first run? That's plan. Any comments?

Comment: I think that you must to use pure PHP and SQL queries to do this job. There is wp_postmeta table into Wordpress database. You can insert metas, taxonomies and what you need with WPDB class, but you need to know names of tables and cells. Look for something about SQL queries and PHP functions for SQL